# The latex template found on my unipage does not work, can't find why

Tags: formatting, templates

Here's [the link](http://www.makro-vwl.uni-kiel.de/de/hinweise-zur-erstellung-wissenschaftlicher-arbeiten)! The one for master thesis.

There are many errors. I'm using TeXstudio.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What errors do you get? Have you installed all relevant packages?

Comment: I tried the BA template. I got it working by a) installing http://emis.mi.sanu.ac.rs/zmath/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurofont/europs.sty and b) changing `\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill}` to `\newcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill}`

Comment: it says File `europs.sty' not found. \usepackage . When I tried samcarter's solution, I got one error "Emergency stop" and a warning "You have requested package `', but the package provides `europs'."  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Druck den Quelltext aus, schreib mit Edding *SCHEIẞDRECK* drauf und häng das ans Schwarze Brett. So einen Müll sollte keiner als Vorlage nutzen. Warne die anderen Studenten.

Comment: https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-Kompendium:_LaTeX_für_wissenschaftiche_Arbeiten

Answer (score 1):

All templates work for me with a full MiKTeX installation after changing

```
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill}
```

without errors or warnings.

However, the templates are a little bit outdated as a quick look at [l2tabu](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/german/l2tabu/l2tabu.pdf) shows. For example `{\bf Text}` should be `\textbf{Text}`. And so on.

But I do not expect, that anybody of the “experts” at CAU Kiel is going to update the templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've also installed a MikTeX but still not working. Should I install MacTeX?

Comment: The error it says is " File `europs.sty' not found. \usepackage" btw.

Comment: Put a `%` in front of that line. -> `%\usepackage{europs}`. Better would be to not use the template at all.